# Attempt to connect from SpringBoot to docker-postgres failed

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I have created a docker container based on a postgres image.

Which I try to connect to from a Spring Boot application with no success.

The user is 'postgres', and the password 'password'.

(I don't have anything from Docker Compose, nor do I know if it's necessary.)

I would appreciate any help

[image: related dependencies in pom.xml]

[image: the application.properties file]

[image: the container up]

[image: the error when starting]

Comment: How did you proceed to create the container ?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to replace the images with the actual code and error message, including the details @cisco_bro asks for?

Comment: Changing to port 5433 and especifying POSTGRES_USER=postgres do the work. Thank you anywhay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved:

1. Remove all previous containers.
2. Create new container. This time using port 5433 and expecifying the postgres user.

   docker run --name container-postgres-1 -p 5433:5432 -v "C:\volumen-docker-1:/var/lib/postgresql/data" -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -d postgres:13.9-alpine3.17
3. Create the database bootifyone.

   docker exec -it container-postgres-1 bash

   psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres

   CREATE DATABASE bootifyone;
4. Using this connection URL in the **application.properties**:

   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/bootifyone

Comment: You can pass the database via the env `POSTGRES_DB` instead of step 3.